# How to parse keywords as normal words some of the time in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I have a language with keywords like `hello` that are only keywords in certain types of sentences.  In other types of sentences, these words should be matched as an ID, for example.  Here's a super simple grammar that tells the story:

```
grammar Hello;

file : ( sentence )* ;
sentence : 'hello' ID PERIOD
         | INT ID PERIOD;

ID  : [a-z]+ ;
INT : [0-9]+ ;
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
PERIOD : '.' ;
```

I'd like these sentences to be valid:

```
hello fred.
31 cheeseburgers.
6 hello.
```

but that last sentence doesn't work in this grammar.  The word `hello` is a token of type `hello` and not of type `ID`.  It seems like the lexer grabs all the hellos and turns them into tokens of that type.

Here's a crazy way to do it, to explain what I want:

```
sentence : 'hello' ID PERIOD
         | INT crazyID PERIOD;

crazyID : ID | 'hello' ;
```

but in my real language, there are a lot of keywords like hello to deal with, so, yeah, that way seems crazy.

Is there a reasonable, compact, target-language-independent way to handle this?

Comment: ANTLR may have specific support for this scenario, but otherwise couldn't you just do something like `sentence : ID ID PERIOD` and then check that the first ID equals `hello` during semantic analysis?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  This makes the grammar simple to write and works but it makes my overall job a bit harder than the answer below by @GRosenberg.

Comment: No worries, I believe GRosenberg is the resident ANTLR expert, and I use something else on a daily basis, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard way of handling keywords:

```
file     : ( sentence )* EOF ;
sentence : key=( KEYWORD | INT ) id=( KEYWORD | ID ) PERIOD ;

KEYWORD : 'hello' | 'goodbye' ; // list others as alts
PERIOD  : '.' ;
ID      : [a-z]+ ;
INT     : [0-9]+ ;
WS      : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

The seeming ambiguity between the `KEYWORD` and `ID` rules is resolved based on the `KEYWORD` rule being listed before the `ID` rule.

In the parser SentenceContext, TerminalNode variables `key` and `id` will be generated and, on parsing, will effectively hold the matched tokens, allowing easy positional identification.