# Non-greedy matching of tokens from lists in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

In [a previous question with a simple grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755469/how-to-parse-keywords-as-normal-words-some-of-the-time-in-antlr4/38757428#38757428), I learned to handle IDs that can include keywords from a keyword list.  My actual grammar is a little more complex: there are several lists of keywords that are expected in different types of sentences.  Here's my attempt at a simple grammar that tells the story:

```
grammar Hello;

file     : ( fixedSentence )* EOF ;
sentence : KEYWORD1 ID+ KEYWORD2 ID+ PERIOD
         | KEYWORD3 ID+ KEYWORD4 ID+ PERIOD;

KEYWORD1 : 'hello' | 'howdy' | 'hi' ;
KEYWORD2 : 'bye' | 'goodbye' | 'adios' ;
KEYWORD3 : 'dear' | 'dearest' ;
KEYWORD4 : 'love' | 'yours' ;
PERIOD  : '.' ;
ID      : [a-z]+ ;
WS      : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

So the sentences I want to match are, for example:

```
hello snickers bar goodbye mars bar.
dear peter this is fun yours james.
```

and that works great.  But I also want to match sentences that contain keywords that would not be expected to terminate the ID+ block.  For example

```
hello hello kitty goodbye my dearest raggedy ann and andy.
```

`hello` fist appears as `KEYWORD1` and then just following as part of that first ID+.  Following the example of the above linked question, I can fix it like this:

```
// ugly solution:
fixedSentence : KEYWORD1 a=(ID|KEYWORD1|KEYWORD3|KEYWORD4)+ KEYWORD2 b=(ID|KEYWORD1|KEYWORD2|KEYWORD3|KEYWORD4)+ PERIOD
              | KEYWORD3 a=(ID|KEYWORD1|KEYWORD2|KEYWORD3)+ KEYWORD4 b=(ID|KEYWORD1|KEYWORD2|KEYWORD3|KEYWORD4)+ PERIOD;
```

which works and does exactly what I'd like.  In my real language, I've got hundreds of keyword lists, to be used in different types of sentences, so if I try for this approach, I'll certainly make a mistake doing this, and when I create new structures in my language, I have to go back and edit all the others.

What would be nice is to do non-greedy matching from a list, following the ANTLR4 book's examples for comments.  So I tried this

```
// non-greedy matching concept:
KEYWORD : KEYWORD1 | KEYWORD2 | KEYWORD3 | KEYWORD4 ;
niceID : ( ID | KEYWORD ) ;
niceSentence : KEYWORD1 niceID+? KEYWORD2 niceID+? PERIOD
             | KEYWORD2 niceID+? KEYWORD3 niceID+? PERIOD;
```

which I think follows the model for comments (e.g. given on p.81 of the book):

```
COMMENT : '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip ;
```

by using the `?` to suggest non-greediness.  (Though the example is a lexer rule, does that change the meaning here?)  `fixedSentence` works but `niceSentence` is a failure.  Where do I go from here?

---

To be specific, the errors reported in parsing the hello kitty test sentence above are,

Testing rule `sentence`:

```
line 1:6 extraneous input 'hello' expecting ID
line 1:29 extraneous input 'dearest' expecting {'.', ID}
```

Testing rule `fixedSentence`: no errors.

Testing rule `niceSentence`:

```
line 1:6 extraneous input 'hello' expecting {ID, KEYWORD}
line 1:29 extraneous input 'dearest' expecting {KEYWORD2, ID, KEYWORD}
line 1:57 extraneous input '.' expecting {KEYWORD2, ID, KEYWORD}
```

And if it helps to see the parse trees, [here they are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qKzm.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recognize that the parser is ideally suited to handling syntax, *i.e.*, structure, and not semantic distinctions. Whether a keyword is an `ID` terminator in one context and not in another, both being syntactically equivalent, is inherently semantic.

The typical ANTLR approach to handling semantic ambiguities is to create a parse tree recognizing as many structural distinctions as reasonably possible, and then walk the tree analyzing each node in relation to the surrounding nodes (in this case) to resolve ambiguities.

If this resolves to your parser being

```
sentences : ( ID+ PERIOD )* EOF ;
```

then your sentences are essentially free form.  The more appropriate tool might be an NLP library - Stanford has a nice one.

**Additional**

If you define your lexer rules as

```
KEYWORD1 : 'hello' | 'howdy' | 'hi' ;
KEYWORD2 : 'bye' | 'goodbye' | 'adios' ;
KEYWORD3 : 'dear' | 'dearest' ;
KEYWORD4 : 'love' | 'yours' ;
. . . .
KEYWORD : KEYWORD1 | KEYWORD2 | KEYWORD3 | KEYWORD4 ;
```

the lexer will never emit a `KEYWORD` token - 'hello' is consumed and emitted as a KEYWORD1 and the `KEYWORD` rule is never evaluated. Since the parse tree fails to identify the type of the tokens (apparently) it is not very illuminating. Dump the token stream to see what the lexer is actually doing

```
hello    hello    kitty goodbye  my dearest  ...
KEYWORD1 KEYWORD1 ID    KEYWORD2 ID KEYWORD3 ...
```

If you place the `KEYWORD` rule before the others, then the lexer is going to only emit `KEYWORD` tokens.

Changing to parser rules

```
niceID : ( ID | keyword ) ;
keyword : KEYWORD1 | KEYWORD2 | KEYWORD3 | KEYWORD4 ;
```

will allow this very limited example to work.

Comment: Thanks for your insight here.  Thanks also for the link to Stanford CoreNLP, which I will study more (though I am solving a different and easier problem, I hope).  Meanwhile, though, why can I make a comment like `/* /* */` which seems a lot like what I want.  The token `/*` is used as a "keyword" the first time, as some contents the second time, and the `.*?` doesn't eat up the final `*/` -- all of which is the behavior I want.  Is there a way to adapt that mechanism to my problem?

Comment: What was your error message with `niceSentence`? What input string did you test with?

Comment: I added the errors and the parse trees to the bottom of the original question.  Also, as an experiment, I tried niceSentence and niceID as lexer rules, which might be silly, but I thought it would bring it closer to the comment example.  No joy there.  Can you make sense of what's going on with it here, with the help of those errors?

Comment: "... the lexer will never emit a KEYWORD token" YES OF COURSE!  Once again, you've put me on the right path.  Thank you!